# Selecting first row of datagrid when WPF form is loaded

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF window, I have a Textbox bound to a DataGrid, already filled with data. When I select a different row, the text in the textbox changes correctly.
However when the WPF is loaded, there is no selection at first, so the textbox stays empty. Only when I actually select a row, the binding to the textbox takes place.

How can I achieve that when the form is loaded, the first row of the DataGrid is automaticly selected and so the textbox is filled.

Here is how I bind the textbox to the datagrid (XAML):

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtContactNaam" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Text  = "{Binding ElementName = dgContacten, Path = SelectedItem.[Naam], 
     Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
```

Thanks for your help.

A bit more code:

```
public partial class wpfTest_2 : Window
```

{
DataTable dtContacten;

```
DataSet dsContacten = new DataSet("Contacten");

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MaakTabellen();
    VulTabellen();

    dgContacten.ItemsSource = dtContacten.DefaultView;
}

private void MaakTabellen()
{
    dtContacten = new DataTable("Contacten");
    dsContacten.Tables.Add(dtContacten);

    dtContacten.Columns.Add("Naam", typeof(string));
    dtContacten.Columns.Add("Voornaam", typeof(string));
}

private void VulTabellen()
{
    ToevoegenDataContacten("Vanderbeke", "Michel");
    ToevoegenDataContacten("Maes", "Maddy");
    ToevoegenDataContacten("Pieters", "Jan");
}

private void ToevoegenDataContacten(string naam, string voornaam)
{
    DataRow nieuwContact = dsContacten.Tables["Contacten"].NewRow();

    nieuwContact["Naam"] = naam;
    nieuwContact["Voornaam"] = voornaam;

    dsContacten.Tables["Contacten"].Rows.Add(nieuwContact);
}
```

}

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgContacten" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="10" Margin="10,10,10,10" RowBackground="LightYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue" ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding Row, Mode=TwoWay}"></DataGrid>

<TextBox x:Name="txtContactNaam" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="11" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Text  = "{Binding ElementName = dgContacten, Path = SelectedItem.[Naam], 
     Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtContactVoornaam" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="12" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="10,10,10,10" Text  = "{Binding ElementName = dgContacten, Path = SelectedItem.[Voornaam],
     Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

Hope this clarifies my problem.

Comment: please add DataGrid xaml, and code which fills data

Answer (score 0):

you can set selected row after assigning ItemsSource:

```
dgContacten.ItemsSource = dtContacten.DefaultView;
dgContacten.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

btw, the following bindings are not doing anything:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Table}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Row, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

because

- you reset ItemsSource in code
- you don't assign DataContext
- properties Table and Row don't exist

Comment: Yes, I did already try dgContacten.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: Yes, I did already try
dgContacten.SelectedIndex = 0;
but that did not help to select the first row of the DataGrid on the load of the form. I still need to click on a row in order for the data to appear in the textboxes.

The bindings you mentioned, I already removed them from my XAML-code.

The question remains: how can I select a row automaticaly after form_load?